# How to copy tab values to cells in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Dear Fellow StackOverFlow-members,

I try to copy tab content to a range of cells. For example if I have 5 values in my tab, I want to copy each value to 5 different cells. So 1 value of tab to 1 cells.

I tried to loop over the range of cells and loop over tab like the following code. But I only get 5 in every cells.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim tabtest(4) As Integer
tabtest(0) = 1
tabtest(1) = 2
tabtest(2) = 3
tabtest(3) = 4
tabtest(4) = 5

For i = 5 To 10
For j = 0 To 4
Sheets("Câbles").Range("A" & i).Value = tabtest(j)
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I want to learn from this, so if possible, explain me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: `i` will need to increase in line with `j` otherwise, you'll just get the last value in each.  `j` will finish before your `next I` is called, so `I` will remain at 5 for the first loop of j, then it will remain at 6....

Comment: What do you mean by `tab` the sheet names?  This can be accessed from the `worksheets` collection

Comment: @Nathan_Sav So if I understand what you say, the `j` loop will loop until the last value before going out of the loop and the next `i` value, right ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav And this is why Siddharth, in the 1st answer, says I don't need a second loop as `j` and `i` need to insrease at the same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the 2nd loop. Also you have 5 values in the Tab so the first loop has to be `5` to `9` and not `5` to `10`. Instead of `10` or `9` you can also use `Ubound(tabtest)` to achieve what you want.

Is this what you are trying?

```
j = 0
For i = 5 To 9
    Sheets("Câbles").Range("A" & i).Value = tabtest(j)
    j = j + 1
Next i
```

Using `Ubound`

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim startRow As Long

    Dim tabtest(4) As Integer
    tabtest(0) = 1
    tabtest(1) = 2
    tabtest(2) = 3
    tabtest(3) = 4
    tabtest(4) = 5

    startRow = 5

    For i = startRow To (startRow + UBound(tabtest))
        Sheets("Câbles").Range("A" & i).Value = tabtest(j)
        j = j + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: it works so fine thank you. It make sense to loop from 5 to 9 when you say it now. I didn't know Ubound, as I'm beginning VBA, and I saw there is also Lbound too Thanks. I got a last question is why the 2 loop make me display only the last value in my tab ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running two separate loops.  In reality, **no** loops are needed:

```
Sub test()
    Dim tabtest(4) As Integer

    tabtest(0) = 1
    tabtest(1) = 2
    tabtest(2) = 3
    tabtest(3) = 4
    tabtest(4) = 5

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Sheets("Câbles").Range("A5").Resize(UBound(tabtest) + 1, 1).Value = .Transpose(tabtest)
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

You use `TRANSPOSE()` to move an array into a **column** of cells.  You don't need `TRANSPOSE()` to move the array into a **row** of cells.

Comment: This looks like sorcery to me ^^ If I understand, you extend the range with `Resize` to match the range from A5 to A9, right ? However I'm not sure how to use `Transpose`, do number of values need to match number of cells ?

Comment: @LyessD  You are exactly correct...............because the array is **5** items, I make sure the range of cells is also **5** cells.

Comment: @LyessD  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you for the explanations